# Errors when trying to adding points to a plot3

Tags: matlab, plot

I'm trying to dynamically add information to a 3D plot:

```
A = [ -8/3 0 0; 0 -10 10; 0 28 -1 ];
y = [35 -10 -7]';
h = 0.01;
p = plot3(y(1),y(2),y(3),'.','EraseMode','none','MarkerSize',2);
axis([0 50 -25 25 -25 25])
hold on
while 1
    A(1,3) = y(2);
    A(3,1) = -y(2);
    ydot = A*y;
    y = y + h*ydot;
    set(p,'XData',y(1),'YData',y(2),'ZData',y(3))
    drawnow
end
```

I get the following errors:

> Warning: The EraseMode property is no longer supported and will error
>   in a future release.
>
> In strange_attractor (line 4)  Warning: The EraseMode property is no longer supported and will error in a future release.
>
> In strange_attractor (line 4)  Error using matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line/set Invalid or deleted object.
>
> Error in strange_attractor (line 12)
>       set(p,'XData',y(1),'YData',y(2),'ZData',y(3))

I understand that I'm using the outdated syntax for dynamically updating the plot that is no longer supported. How do I make it work?

Note that I don't want to call `plot3` inside the loop, because it makes the graphing slow and consumes a lot of memory. I hope to call plot3 once and just add new points to the existing plot inside the loop. Can it be done in the new version?

Matlab version: R2018a

Comment: Please see the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/how-do-i-replace-the-erasemode-property.html)

Comment: Thanks Sardar, I have read the documentation but I have not idea how to make my example work.

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: When you want to dynamically add information, do you intend to keep the previously plotted values as well?

Comment: Yes, I do want to keep previously plotted points.

Comment: You want to replace your `plot3` usage outside your loop with `plot3(y(1),y(2),y(3),'.','MarkerSize',2);` and replace `set(.....)`: with this `plot3(y(1),y(2),y(3),'.', 'MarkerSize',2);` ?

Comment: This works thanks. However I'm concerned that it created a new plot object every time and is slow, plus it eats all available memory. The point of my previous example is to use existing plot and just add new points to it in a loop. Can this be accomplished with the new Matlab version?

Comment: How do you expect an infinite loop with no breaking condition  to not take up all the memory?

Comment: You are right. What I meant is that using plot3 each time inside a loop is a bit costly. My intention was to call plot3 once, and then add new points to the existing plot in the while loop. This way it would consume less memory and will run faster. But thanks for your help! :)

Comment: You've got a good answer below, but you can also just remove the `'EraseMode','none'` bit from the `plot3` call and everything should work as before. It is only a warning after all... The error message happened only after you closed the window, didn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your comment above, when you say "This does not work", what do you mean?  A direct modification of your code according to the given link to the documentation works as expected:

```
A = [ -8/3 0 0; 0 -10 10; 0 28 -1 ];
y = [35 -10 -7]';
h = 0.01;
p = animatedline(y(1),y(2),y(3),'Marker','.','MarkerSize',2);
axis([0 50 -25 25 -25 25])
hold on
while 1
    A(1,3) = y(2);
    A(3,1) = -y(2);
    ydot = A*y;
    y = y + h*ydot;
    addpoints(p,y(1),y(2),y(3))
    drawnow
end
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks this is working now! I'm pretty new to Matlab and could not apply the suggestion from the documentation correctly. :)